# C# Simple regex name group capturing

Tags: c#, regex

I have this simple code to capture named regex groups in C#, but only one of the name group value is non-empty. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
var formatter = "yyyy-MM-dd";

var regex = new Regex("(?<month>MM)|(?<day>dd)|(?<year>yyyy|yy)|([^a-zA-Z])");

var match = regex.Match(formatter);

if (match.Success)
{
    var day = match.Groups["day"];
    var month = match.Groups["month"];
    var year = match.Groups["year"];
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to get `year = "yyyy"`, `day = "dd"` and `month = "MM"`

Comment: It looks like your pattern is fixed or do you actually have an input string like `"2018-05-26"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one will get a value because of the OR operator |.
Use the following

```
(?<year>yyyy)-(?<month>MM)-(?<day>dd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why you match on `([^a-zA-Z])` at the end, but you might want to try this: `((?<month>MM)|(?<day>dd)|(?<year>yyyy|yy)|(-))*`

If it doesn't work for you, let me know why you match the end part.